# on click cancel button is hiding value inside textfield

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

we are using magento multivendor/multiseller site.

We are providing an option for vendor to update the price from their account through frontend.

when vendor clicks on update button, its updating price sucessfully.[image]

but **vendor clicks on cancel button, its hiding the value inside textfield**.

[image]

what i need is vendor trying to update price, in that time vendor type some number in textfield and if he clicks on "cancel" button ,it should revert back to original price.

**code for updating price**

```
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>


<script>
function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
</script>
```

**code for cancelling price**

```
<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>


<script>
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />
```

you missed this hidden field.. in your script you are changing value  back to curr

```
<script>
function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: i used your code , but i gave blank, than instead of type="hidden" i used " text", than after updating ,it s giving blank value inside text field.

Comment: can you give me link i will check

Comment: i am asking about ad this field not remove the old field. keep both

Comment: still same issue is there.

Comment: you are missing the value for field add it..

Comment: value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" this value is there for both <input>.

Comment: send me code i will see that